# Get manually defined vectors from Curve3D (Path) in Godot

Tags: path-finding, godot, gdscript

I have a scene containing a `Path` Node (the red dots with the blue lines)

I want to use the Path Node as a list of ordered checkpoints (easy to add with the editor), for a character, with some kind of obstacle avoidance.

I can get the list of all steps along the `Curve3D`, with `$Path.get_curve().get_baked_points()`, the distance between two steps being `$Path.bake_interval`. But that's not what I need for my purpose. I only want the red dots, not all increment, since some of them are inside the obstacles.

Is there any mean to get a list of the red dots from script ? Or some configuration on Path or Curve3D to force all the increments being the red dots ?

Otherwise, could you suggest an alternative way to add, as easily as that, a list of ordered checkpoints ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of points of the curve with `get_point_count`, and then get the position of each one with `get_point_position`. For example:

```
    for index in curve.get_point_count():
        print(curve.get_point_position(index))
```

Should print the positions you want.

Comment: Nice! I don't know how I missed it!